# Deducing type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Let

```
f :: a -> Int
f arg = 2
```

`a` is a type that will be deduced during compilation. Is it possible to learn how did Haskell deduce it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  In this case you haven't used `arg` at all, so there are no constraints on what its type can be, hence GHC deduces that it can be any type `a` (lower case names in types are always type variables).  If you had used it in some way in the definition of `f` then there would potentially be additional constraints on its type, forcing GHC to refine it from "this can be anything".

Comment: If the function was something like `f arg = arg + 2`, then the compiler would infer that `arg :: Num a => a`, since that is required to use `arg` with the `+` operator.

Comment: Yes, I have not used arg. But, I presented only simple situation.

Comment: @chepner, yes. But how to check it

Comment: Are you asking how GHC chooses the type `a -> Int` for `f`, or how GHC chooses what type to assign to `a` when you call `f`? These are very different questions. bheklilr and chepner above are commenting about the first question. But the second question is interesting, too.

Comment: No. We called `f` somewhere in the code. So, compiler had to deduced type  of  argument. How to check what type was deduced?

Comment: If the compiler doesn't already know the type of `x`, `f x` doesn't provide it with any additional information.

Comment: It seems like you want the compiler to notify you every time the `a` in the type of `f` is instantiated with a type (and in particular, which type was chosen)?

Comment: @user2407038, yes. Or I can load a HS file in the ghci and then.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether this is actually useful... but here is one way:

```
> import Data.Typeable
> let argType f x = let _ = f x in typeOf x
```

Example:

```
> let f :: a->Int ; f arg = 2
> argType f 'a'
Char
> argType f 1
Integer
```

The last example shows the actual type of `1`, after GHC(i) defaulting.

---

A simpler alternative, working even in source files: when we have

```
foo (bar x) (baz y)
```

and we want to know the type of `y`, we can just replace it with

```
foo (bar x) (baz (asTypeOf _ y))
```

We will get an error such as

```
    • Found hole: _ :: Integer
```

which tells us the type of `y`. Downside: we have to revert the code back for it to compile.

---

As a more low-level alternative, compile with `-ddump-simpl` and observe the scary GHC Core which is being produced. There, every type argument is made explicit: we could read something like `f @ Char 'a'`, where names could be possibly mangled a bit, e.g. `Main.a$f @ GHC.Char 'a'`, but it should still be possible to understand what's going on.